# deep Populating based on parent conditon

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a model

lets say,

```
var ModelA= new Schema({
  x:string,
  y:refrence to model y
})
```

then in model y

```
var ModelY=new Schema({
  hidden:{type:Boolean,default:false},
  z:reference to model z
})
```

And again in model z, I have multiple fields

```
var ModelZ=new Schema({
  p:string,
  q:number 
  ... and other fields
})
```

So my query goes this way for populating the required result

```
ModelA.find({x:1}).populate('y')
```

so after populating y, I want to populate (z) those documents which are having hidden== true else leave as it is( ie. ObjcectId)

Please suggest the query
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
Mode.find().populate({ path: "y", populate: { path: "z" } })
```

But what I suggest you to go with [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) query to do this instead of populate

Comment: I need to check the hidden==true condition before populating. And  i have tried  both populate and lookup but none are working

Comment: `$lookup` will work here... If you put your actual collection and data I will show you how to do this